# Recyclerview over other views

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `Recyclerview` and two other views(`ImageView` and `TextView`) above `Recyclerview`.

I want that initially `Recyclerview` should stay below `ImageView` and `TextView` but when the `user` scrolls the `Recyclerview` it should come over the other views.

[image]

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBlack">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivProfile"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_vertical_half_margin"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ivProfile"
        tools:text="Prithvi Bhola" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvName"
        tools:text="prithvi.leo08@gmail.com" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLiked"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_vertical_margin"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
        android:text="@string/liked"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvEmail" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivStaggered"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_vertical_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_view_compact_black_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvEmail" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvLikedPalettes"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvLiked" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvEmptyList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_regular"
        android:text="@string/empty_liked_palette"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvLiked" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Show ur xml file

Comment: May be https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout

Comment: @Piyush please check the edits

Comment: @NileshRathod I want this in a `Fragment` which is in the `ViewPager` so won't be able to use `CollapsingToolbarLayout `.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it via collapsing toolbar layout.

below is sample code.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_height="300dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:contentScrim="?colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="49dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

              </YOUR HEADER LAYOUT HERE/>


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_flexible_space"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I want this inside the `Fragment` which is in the `ViewPager` so won't be able to use `CollapsingToolbarLayout` and `Toolbar`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dp350"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header_image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dp350"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:title="@string/app_name"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_collapseMode="none"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I want this inside the Fragment which is in the ViewPager so won't be able to use CollapsingToolbarLayout and Toolbar.

Comment: set your fragment layout by using this xml.

Answer (score 0):

In your hierarchy, make sure your RecyclerView is placed above the ImageView and Textview. Then you can just add the following properties on your recyclerview in the xml :

`android:clipToPadding="false"
 android:paddingTop="xxxdp"`

The property `clipToPadding` to false is the key !

If you need a dynamic paddingTop, you can programmatically get the `bottom` of the view which must be right above the Recyclerview and set it as the paddingTop on your RecyclerView.

Note : Your recyclerview background must be transparent and you have to set à non-transparent background on each of your recyclerview's and it will work.

Here is a quick example with FrameLayout but you can use a ConstraintLayout if you prefer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MY TEXT"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="200dp"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Edit : Here is the same example with ConstraintLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MY TEXT"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/imageView"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="200dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why do you think that fragment in viewpager can't hold collapsing toolbar. Because it can be done with all answers given above. As none of them mentioned the java code for it let me add one for you.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

       //your code here

</android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

In the java code of your fragment call your collapsing toolbar like this.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout=(CollapsingToolbarLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.collapse_toolbar);
    return rootView;
}
```

And you will have your desired behaviour.

**EDIT**

Adding a demo gif for preview.

[image: Demo GIF]